# "TypeError: reading_in() missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, arguments, position, opencsv

First time user and new to Python, so I only have very basic level of understanding. I am trying FUNCTIONS using PARAMETERS and I am coming around this error:

```
"TypeError: reading_in() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surname1' "
```

When I try to read from the CSV file. Please HELP!

```
# Code block to Read customer data from a csv file
    elif(user_choice.lower()=="r"):
        backend.reading_in(plans)
```

---

```
# Read from a csv file code function
def reading_in(name1,surname1):  
    in_file_obj = open("customer_plan.csv","r")
    line=in_file_obj.readline()
    while(line !=""):
        fields = line.strip().split(",")
        plan_index= int(fields[0])
        name = fields[1]
        surname = fields[2]
        name_surname = name + " " + surname
        backend.add_plan(plans[plan_index],name_surname)
        line= in_file_obj.readline()
    in_file_obj.close()
```

Comment: Hello tim, welcome to SO. As you can see, you define the function with two input parameters: `name1` and `surname1`. But in your `elif` statement, you include only one input: `plans` for `name1`. So you either need to change the function, or you need to provide one more input.

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? In `backend.reading_in(plans)` there is only one argument `plans` when it expects 2 - `name1` and `surname1`.

Comment: Also, check [ask]. We expect [mre] as well as fulltraceback.